# Pandas to create columns based on starting Character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below data parsed Data from the Linux Machine into a text file.

What i Want..

> 1. Any line Startswith `cn:` should be comes under column `Group_Name` by constituting it.
> 2. Below `cn:` there are lines starting `nisNetgroupTriple:`, value after this is hostname should comes under Column `Host_Name`.
> 3. Where there is only `Group_Name` just need to be None in the `Host_Name` column

I am able to do that in Shell way but looking it in Pandas way..

### Sample Data.

Below is just sample data but the actual data is Much bigger..

```
cn: Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1562.khatigusain.com.com
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1187.khatigusain.com.com

cn: Infra_RDC_IMEC_US-KDC02_SWDC02_SW

cn: Infra_RDC_APAC_CN-KHA02_SWHA02_SW

cn: Infra_SAT_EMEA_AT-GRK02_RS_SW

cn: Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1402.khatigusain.com.com
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1964.khatigusain.com.com
```

### DataFrame:

```
                      cn: Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01
0  nisNetgroupTriple: kht1562.khatigusain.com.com
1  nisNetgroupTriple: kht1187.khatigusain.com.com
2           cn: Infra_RDC_IMEC_US-KDC02_SWDC02_SW
3           cn: Infra_RDC_APAC_CN-KHA02_SWHA02_SW
4               cn: Infra_SAT_EMEA_AT-GRK02_RS_SW
5                     cn: Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04
6  nisNetgroupTriple: kht1402.khatigusain.com.com
7  nisNetgroupTriple: kht1964.khatigusain.com.com
Index(['cn: Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01'], dtype='object')
```

### Desired Data:

```
Group_Name                              Host_Name
Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01                 kht1562.khatigusain.com.com
Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01                 kht1187.khatigusain.com.com
Infra_RDC_IMEC_US-KDC02_SWDC02_SW       None
Infra_RDC_APAC_CN-KHA02_SWHA02_SW       None
Infra_SAT_EMEA_AT-GRK02_RS_SW           None
Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04                 kht1402.khatigusain.com.com 
Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04                 kht1964.khatigusain.com.com
```

I tried to lot googling around and tried to get some clue but didn't get anything, i'm still trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to prepare data in a suitable way. This is how you could do that:

### Demo data in file:

```
with open ("data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""cn: Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1562.khatigusain.com.com
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1187.khatigusain.com.com

cn: Infra_RDC_IMEC_US-KDC02_SWDC02_SW

cn: Infra_RDC_APAC_CN-KHA02_SWHA02_SW

cn: Infra_SAT_EMEA_AT-GRK02_RS_SW

cn: Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1402.khatigusain.com.com
nisNetgroupTriple: kht1964.khatigusain.com.com""")
```

### Read and parse data into dict - and create df from dict:

```
data = {}

with open("data.txt") as f:
    key = None 
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip(): 
            continue
        if line.startswith("cn:"):
            key = line.split(":",1)[1].strip()
            data.setdefault(key, []) # key can have multiple occurences in file
        elif line.startswith("nisNetgroupTriple:"):
            data[key].append(line.split(":",1)[1].strip())
print(data)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( (k,v.strip() or None) for k,va in data.items() for v in (va or " ") ) 
df.columns = ["Group_Name","Host_Name"]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                          Group_Name                    Host_Name
0  Infra_RDC_APAC_CN-KHA02_SWHA02_SW                         None        
1            Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01  kht1562.khatigusain.com.com
2            Infra_SAT_IMEC_TR-KPQ01  kht1187.khatigusain.com.com
3  Infra_RDC_IMEC_US-KDC02_SWDC02_SW                         None    
4            Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04  kht1402.khatigusain.com.com
5            Infra_SAT_APAC_CN-KPH04  kht1964.khatigusain.com.com
6      Infra_SAT_EMEA_AT-GRK02_RS_SW                         None
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick for extending a help, +1, I am checking it with my data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

Assuming original data is stored in a dataframe called 'df' and a column name 'sample'

Extract the contents following the string contents 'cn' and 'nisNetgroupTriple' into separate columns:

```
df['Group_Name']=df['sample'].str.extract('cn:(.*)')
df['Host_Name']=df['sample'].str.extract('nisNetgroupTriple:(.*)')
```

Then forward fill the 'Group_Name' column with contents

```
df['Group_Name']=df['Group_Name'].ffill()
```

Then delete rows where the 'Group_Name' is 'non-unique' AND the value of the 'Host_Name' in the column next to it is 'nan':

First check for uniqueness:

```
df['Group_Name_unique']=df.groupby('Group_Name')['Group_Name'].transform('size')
```

Then set the condition:

```
drop_rows=(df['Group_Name_unique']>1)&(df['Host_Name']).isnull()
```

Obtain results and drop unnecessary columns:

```
result=df.loc[~drop_rows]
result=result.drop(['sample','Group_Name_unique'],axis=1)
```